# CSV file is not getting data from buffor

Tags: c++

I'm learning to code in C++ and I'm doing some examples of file operations. There is no problem to send to file text data when it is saved as .txt file.

However I went further and experiment on csv files:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

 int main ()
{
int num = 0;

fstream file;

string file_name;

cout << "Input file name: ";
cin>>file_name;
file.open(file_name.c_str());

if (file.fail())
{
    cout << "Unable to open file - try again" << endl;
    main ();
} else
{

file << "VALUE" << "\t" << "1/x" << "\t" << "sqrt" << endl;


while (num < 200)
{
    file << num << "\t" << 1/num << "\t" << sqrt(num) << endl;
    num ++;
}

file.close();
return 0;
}
}
```

When I'm checking the file - there is only header:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq04B.png)

What should I do to write into this csv file - results of these mathematical operations?

Comment: you have division by zero on the first iteration of loop

Comment: try with `num = 1` and  check.

Comment: Calling `main()` is also not allowed in C++.   If you want to loop until a file is successfully opened, use a loop construct - don't call `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment regarding division by zero. Also do not use integers for division. Change

```
while (num < 200)
{
    file << num << "\t" << 1/num << "\t" << sqrt(num) << endl;
    num ++;
}
```

to

```
while(num < 200)
{
    num++;
    file << num << "\t" << 1.0 / num << "\t" << sqrt(num) << endl;
}
```